# how to compare month-year with DateParse

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to check if a date (month-year) is minus than actual date.

I know how to do it only with single month or year, like

```
DateTime.Parse(o.MyDate).Month <= DateTime.Now.Month
```

or

```
DateTime.Parse(o.MyDate).Year <= DateTime.Now.Year
```

but how can I check directly if month-year is minus than now.month-now.year?

**EDIT**

What I have to do is, for example, to check if 10-2011 (DateTime.Now.Month-DateTime.Now.Year) is between 01-2011 and 04-2012...

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: Will `Parse` always work for you ? parse it once and then play around with the values from the parsed instance, would be simpler

Comment: for example, I have to check if 10-2011 (now) is between 01-2011 and 04-2012...

Comment: Why are there three dates? Are there any more dates than o.MyDate and DateTime.Now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the years are the same, compare the months, if the years are not the same, your year must be smaller than now:

```
var yourDate = ...;
if((yourDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && yourDate.Month < DateTime.Now.Month)
   || yourDate.Year < DateTime.Now.Year)
{
    // yourDate is smaller than todays month.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To check if `yourDate` is in a certain time range, use this:

```
var yourDate = ...;
var lowerBoundYear = 2011;
var lowerBoundMonth = 1;
var upperBoundYear = 2012;
var upperBoundMonth = 4;

if(((yourDate.Year == lowerBoundYear && yourDate.Month >= lowerBoundMonth) || 
    yourDate.Year > lowerBoundYear
   ) &&
   ((yourDate.Year == upperBoundYear && yourDate.Month <= upperBoundMonth) ||
    yourDate.Year < lowerBoundYear
   ))
{
    // yourDate is in the time range 01/01/2011 - 30/04/2012
    // if you want yourDate to be in the range 01/02/2011 - 30/04/2012, i.e. 
    // exclusive lower bound, change the >= to >.
    // if you want yourDate to be in the range 01/01/2011 - 31/03/2012, i.e.
    // exclusive upper bound, change the <= to <.
}
```

Comment: I've update my target. It won't work with this code. Sorry, wasnt clear :) Hope now you can understand what I'm looking for...

Comment: I know how to do this using single month or year. But is not what I asked :) Is if I can check directly the pari month-year...

Comment: @markzzz: My answer checks exactly what you asked. It checks if a certain date is in a range of dates. Month/Year is a date, too, it is equivalent to 01/Month/Year. Please try to understand the code again. I updated my answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: yes, but checking first year, than month. not directly year-month. That's what I asked...but ok if I can't do it I'll use your own code :)

Comment: Thankyou, very simple but very hard at the same time... And more when you have some days coding continously...

Answer (score 8):

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(o.MyDate);
var year = date.Year;

// We don't even want to know what could happen at 31 Dec 23.59.59 :-)
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
var currentYear = currentTime.Year;

bool result = year < currentYear || 
                 (year == currentYear && 
                     date.Month <= currentTime.Month)
```

Second option:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(o.MyDate).Date; // We round to the day
date = date.AddDays(-date.Day); // and we remove the day

var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(-currentDate.Day);

bool result = date <= currentDate;
```

Third option (more "old school" perhaps)

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(o.MyDate);
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

// Each year can be subdivided in 12 parts (the months)
bool result = date.Year * 12 + date.Month <= currentTime.Year * 12 + currentTime.Month;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime dateCheck = DateTime.Parse(o.MyDate);
bool result = ((Now.Month - dateCheck.Month) + 12 * (Now.Year - dateCheck.Year)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date1 = new DateTime(year1, month1, 1);
var date2 = new DateTime(year2, month2, 1);

if(date1 < date2)...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Date date1 = new Date(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Date date2 = new Date(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0);

int result = DateCompare(date1, date2);
```

if the result is < 0 then date1 < date2
if the result is 0 then date1 == date2
if the result is > 0 the date1 > date2